# List wait and its categories on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I try to get wait types and its categories in one query. I currently Have below query;

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats

This lists wait types but i need wait types categories also like below. How can write this query?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I heard about categories only in relation to sys.query_store_wait_stats [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#wait-categories-mapping-table). And there is no any mention of a designated table with all the categories listed.

I'm afraid you have to keep you own mapping of wait_type -> category to create such a query.